# Difference in scores returned by cross_val_score and my custom implementation of cross validated score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I implemented my custom `cross_val_score` function. But the results are different than those obtained using sklearn's `cross_val_score`.

```
modelType = SGDClassifier(random_state=7)

cv2 = StratifiedKFold(5)

scores = cross_val_score(modelType, XTrainSc, yTrain, cv=cv2, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1)
print(scores)


modelType = SGDClassifier(random_state=7)

ss=[]

for ti, vi in cv2.split(XTrainSc, yTrain):
  print(str(len(ti))+" "+str(len(vi)))
  model = clone(modelType)
  model.fit(XTrainSc[ti], yTrain[ti])
  preds = model.predict(XTrainSc[vi])
  ss.append(np.mean(preds==yTrain[vi]))


print(ss)
```

Here `scores` and `ss` are not equal. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by _not equal_? Please post `scores` and `ss`.

Comment: I mean element wise not equal.

Comment: Are you sure the code you have posted is the code you have run?

Comment: Yes. pretty sure

Answer (score 0):

`StratifiedKfold` also has randomness part in it when it decides the indices for each fold. Hence, setting `random_state` is essential to get reproducibility.

Here is an reproducible example:

```
>>> from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, StratifiedKFold
>>> from sklearn.base import clone
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X, y = datasets.load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)


model = linear_model.SGDClassifier(random_state=7)

cv2 = StratifiedKFold(5,random_state=0)

scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=cv2, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1)
print(scores)


model = linear_model.SGDClassifier(random_state=7)

ss=[]

for ti, vi in cv2.split(X, y):
  print(str(len(ti))+" "+str(len(vi)))
  model = clone(model)
  model.fit(X[ti], y[ti])
  preds = model.predict(X[vi])
  ss.append(np.mean(preds==y[vi]))


print(ss)
```

Output:

```
[0.91304348 0.70434783 0.45132743 0.38938053 0.38053097]
454 115
454 115
456 113
456 113
456 113
[0.9130434782608695, 0.7043478260869566, 0.45132743362831856, 0.3893805309734513, 0.3805309734513274]
```